# Lego 21323 Grand Piano - After setting up app on page 110 of instruction, the gear is turning anti-clockwise instead of clockwise as shown

Tags: building, motor

After completing all builds till page 108 of the instructions, I installed the app. But when I press play on a song the gear move for a quarter turn anti-clockwise but the picture on page 110 shows clockwise.

What should I do

[image: 21323] (from https://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/21323/Grand_Piano)

Comment: Could you confirm if [Technic, Gear 20 Tooth Bevel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32198#T=C) is installed as shown in the picture? And not on the right (closer to us) side?

Comment: Thanks Alex. You are right. That was the mistake I made. 

Answer (score 3):

Converting comment that lead to an answer.

Looking at the picture the first thing that gets my attention is the position of [Technic, Gear 20 Tooth Bevel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32198#T=C). Particular part placement has a room for error - yellow half-bushing, placed on the same axle could easily be swapped with mentioned 20T bevel gear. This kind of error would reverse the rotation when operated.

Could you confirm if  is installed as shown in the picture? And not on the right (closer to us) side?